# What's happening in this while-loop?

Tags: c#, while-loop

```
double number;
bool isParsed = false;

while(!isParsed)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the value");
    isParsed = double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out number);
    if(isParsed)
    {
        break;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid value");
}
```

A friend and I were studying this code block. I found this part to understand:

```
bool isParsed = false;

while(!isParsed)
```

I thought that if isParsed = false, and the while loop will check the negation (!isParsed) to see if it should run, wouldn't this be the logic:

```
while(!isParsed) => while(NOT(false)) => while (true)?
```

Therefore, the while loop would never run. But it does run. Later I understood that a check was happening:

```
while (!isParsed) => while((!isParsed) == true),
```

but he says that not exactly what is happening.

Can someone explain what is happening here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're saying it correctly: `while (true)`. That true boolean condition denotes that the next (and first) iteration will run.

```
!false == true
```

Take a look at the MSDN documentation stating the behavior of the while loop: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2aeyhxcd.aspx

Answer (score 2):

When using a boolean in an expression you are checking for a value of true.  When adding the logical NOT operator, you are now looking for a value of false.

```
while (false)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 bool isParsed = false;

while(!isParsed)
```

Loop should run, at least once; Which is correct behavior, since your condition is evaluating to true.